# how to create a list item with checkbox kivymd?

Tags: checkbox, kivymd

I want to create a list item with a a check box on the left like in the image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzHsZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import IRightBodyTouch, OneLineAvatarIconListItem
from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDCheckbox
from kivymd.icon_definitions import md_icons


KV = '''
<ListItemWithCheckbox>:

    IconLeftWidget:
        icon: root.icon

    RightCheckbox:


MDBoxLayout:

    ScrollView:

        MDList:
            id: scroll
'''


class ListItemWithCheckbox(OneLineAvatarIconListItem):
    '''Custom list item.'''

    icon = StringProperty("android")


class RightCheckbox(IRightBodyTouch, MDCheckbox):
    '''Custom right container.'''


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        icons = list(md_icons.keys())
        for i in range(30):
            self.root.ids.scroll.add_widget(
                ListItemWithCheckbox(text=f"Item {i}", icon=icons[i])
            )


MainApp().run()
```

https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/list/#custom-list-item